# Check if Azure AD user is allowed to access my application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, owin

I have developed an application (asp.net web application) that authenticates using azure ad and asp.net owin. It is a multi-tenant app, so I have registered  my app in azure ad as a multi-tenant app. That means that everyone with a microsoft work/school account can sign in to my application. That is fine, but I need to check if the user signing in has a valid license for using my application. How can I do that? Can I interupt the owin login process somehow and check for a valid license, or how is this normally done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is normally done is to separate AUTHENTICATION (who is the user) from AUTHORIZATION (what can the user do).

I.e. you do NOT interfere with the authentication - the user comes and sends a token. Your app then reacts by redirecting the user to a "create account" page when he is new. That creates in your app the db entry for this user. You can also send him to a "sorry, you have no rights on this application" page.

This allows you to use the same authentication for multiple applications with separate rights and fully separates authentication and authorization.